# Why does StringBuffer/StringBuilder not override equals or hashCode?

Tags: java, oop

Why does StringBuffer/StringBuilder does not override the `equals()`, `hashcode()` methods from object?

Please suggest me clear picture that helps the understand the problem...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because `StringBuffer` is mutable, and its primary use is for *constructing* strings. If you want to compare content, call `StringBuffer#toString()` and compare the returned value.

It is not generally useful to override `hashCode()` for mutable objects, since modifying such an object that is used as a key in a `HashMap` could cause the stored value to be "lost."

Comment: what does Mutable means here?

Comment: Do some research if you don't understand the very basic principles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554192/what-is-a-mutable-class-in-oop

Comment: With all due respect I disagree with your statement _It is not generally useful to override hashCode() for mutable objects..._

Comment: @Shahzeb how about an example of when a mutable object's `hashCode()` might be used?

Comment: First obvious point of reference for me was any ORM class so here is a link from [hibernate](http://tinyurl.com/7qbd7fv) and a long discussion here at SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma

Comment: @MattBall sir can u please elaborate your answer with example of hashmap you are talking about in your answer. I am very close in getting your whole point but still i am confuse a little bit :(

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap the short answer is that `String` is a far better key to use in a `Map` than `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder`.

Comment: @MattBall ok I get it why it is better key ty :)

Answer (score 8):

Actually behind this everything depends upon the hashcode code value. To understand this concept let's take an example :

```
String str1 = new String("sunil");
String str2 = new String("sunil");

HashMap hm = new HashMap()
hm.put(str1,"hello");
hm.put(str2,"bye");
```

final hm:

```
hm = { sunil=bye }
```

In above code, str1 and str2 are two different String objects. Should they be added to the HashMap separately? The answer is **NO**. This is because before inserting/putting a value in HashMap, it internally checks and compares the hashCode values of **str1**, **str2**. Both return the same hashcode value because the String class overrides equals() and hashcode() methods. So upon executing `hm.put(str2,"bye");` first key will get overriden with the new value. Now try this :

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("sunil");
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("sunil");

HashMap hm = new HashMap()
hm.put(sb1,"hello");//sb1 and sb2 will return different HashCode 
hm.put(sb2,"bye");// StringBuffer/StringBuilder does not override hashCode/equals methods
```

final hm:

```
{sunil=hello, sunil=bye}
```

Both value will be added in hashMap because sb1 and sb2 both returns different hashcode. StringBuilder/ StringBuffer does not override equals() and hashCode() method.

*Sun Microsystem wanted the programmer to allow adding 2 different String kind of Values in Hashtable or any other Hash Collections likes (HashSet,HashMap…),that’s the reason hashCode() and equals() were not overridden intentionally in StringBuffer,StringBuilder class.*

Comment: `Sun Microsystem wanted the programmer to allow adding 2 different String kind of Values in Hashtable ...` That's not true, javadocs for  [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) and [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) actively discourage using objects with a broken `equals/hashcode` contract as keys. Storing `StringBuilder` objects in a map isn't useful because you won't be able to get the value by the key unless you have your original object.

Answer (score -1):

Because StringBuffer is **mutable**. With example Try This:)

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class CheckHashcodeEquals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * String class override equals() and hashcode() method thats way
         * override value of HashMap
         */
        String s1 = new String("Arya");
        String s2 = new String("Arya");
        HashMap hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put(s1, "A1");
        hm.put(s2, "A2");
        System.out.println(hm); /* Output: {Arya=A2} */

        /*
         * String class does not override equals() and hashcode() method thats
         * way insert duplicate value
         */
        StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("Arya");
        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("Arya");
        HashMap hm2 = new HashMap<>();
        hm2.put(sb1, "A1");
        hm2.put(sb2, "A2");
        System.out.println(hm2); /* Output: {Arya=A2, Arya=A1} */
    }

}
```

Comment: This example demonstrates that `StringBuffer` doesn't override `equals` and `hashcode`, but doesn't show why. The answer itself (`Because StringBuffer is mutable`) is copied from an earlier answer.